# JavaFX - weird behavior of TreeView on removal of the selected item

Tags: treeview, javafx-8

In my application, I have a `TreeView` at left side, and I update the pane at the right side according to the selection in `TreeView`. A very straight forward scenario. When the selection is null, I show a message like "please make a selection" in the pane, i.e. I also **handle null selection in the `TreeView`**.

During the life time of the application, some items can be added to/removed from the `TreeView`. I had some problems when the selected item in the `TreeView` is removed. In this case, I expected the selection of the `TreeView` to become null, however it is not!

To debug this case, I writed a simple FXML application, as below:

FXMLDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="250.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="treeviewbug.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <TreeView fx:id="treeView" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0" />
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#update" text="update" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0" />
    <Label fx:id="selectionLabel" text="" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController.java:

```
package treeviewbug;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Label selectionLabel;
    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> treeView;
    private TreeItem<String> selectedItem = null;
    private ChangeListener<String> changeListener = new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            selectionLabel.setText(newValue);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        final TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Item " + i));
        }
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);
        treeView.setRoot(root);
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {

            @Override
            public synchronized void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<String>> ov, TreeItem<String> oldSelection, TreeItem<String> newSelection) {
                if (selectedItem != null) {
                    selectedItem.valueProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                }
                if (newSelection == null) {
                    selectionLabel.setText("selection is null");
                } else {
                    selectionLabel.setText(newSelection.getValue());
                }
                selectedItem = newSelection;
                if (selectedItem != null) {
                    selectedItem.valueProperty().addListener(changeListener);
                }
            }
        });
        treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {

            @Override
            public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> p) {
                System.out.println("Creating new cell.");
                return new TreeCell<String>() {

                    Label label = new Label();
                    Button button = new Button("remove");
                    HBox box = new HBox(20);
                    {
                        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                                @Override
                                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                                    TreeItem<String> itemToRemove = null;
                                    for (TreeItem<String> item : root.getChildren()) {
                                        if (item.getValue().equals(getItem())) {
                                            itemToRemove = item;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (itemToRemove != null) {
                                        root.getChildren().remove(itemToRemove);
                                    }
                                    t.consume();
                                }
                            });
                        box.getChildren().addAll(label, button);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String value, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(value, bln);
                        if (value != null) {
                            label.setText(value);
                            setGraphic(box);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void update() {
        TreeItem<String> i = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (i == null) {
            selectionLabel.setText("selection is null");
        } else {
            selectionLabel.setText(i.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Initially, the `TreeView` is populated with 20 items. A listener is attached to `selectedItemProperty` in case the user clicks on some `TreeItem`. A listener is also attached to the `valueProperty` of the selected `TreeItem` in case the user does not click on some item but the value of the selected item changes for some reason. The user can remove a particular item by clicking the remove button within it. At any time, the user can click update button to update the label content that is showing the current selection, in case some event is missed by my handlers.

In this simple test app, when I remove the selected item, it sometimes shows the item just before the removed one as the selected item, and sometimes shows the item just after the removed one as the selected item. **However, the selected item does not change most of time, even if it is not contained in the `TreeView` any more!**

My first question is, is this normal, or a bug? Have you ever seen something like this?

As a workaround, I added the following code right after the for loop:

```
root.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TreeItem<String>> change) {
                while (change.next()) {
                    if (change.wasRemoved() && selectedItem != null) {
                        if (change.getRemoved().contains(selectedItem)) {
                            selectedItem.valueProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                            selectedItem = null;
                            treeView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, there is no weird situation like having a nonexisting item as the selected item. But sometimes the selection is not null, although I call `clearSelection()`. My second question is, is this *auto-selection* normal?

Final question, is there a better workaround?

Sorry, it was a very long question. Thank you if you are still reading :)

Comment: Yup, for me the selection just doesn't update when I remove the last item.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.8.0_92 the behaviour seems to be:

- if an item behind the selection is deleted selectedItem and selectedIndex stay the same,
- if an item before the selection is deleted selectedItem stays the same but selectedIndex changes (because selectedItem changed its position),
- if the selected item is deleted selectedIndex is decremented and selectedItem changes analogous; only if the first item is deleted selectedIndex stays the same.

The only weird behaviour occurs if the last item is deleted. In this case selectedIndex and selectedItem do not change, as Gman also remarked. This leads to an no longer existing item to be selected (seems to be a bug).

As a workaround you can check the root-children in your deletion-code.

The onAction for the delete-button could look like this:

```
button.setOnAction(t -> {
    TreeItem<String> item = getTreeItem();
    item.getParent().getChildren().remove(item);        // remove item
    if(treeView.getRoot().getChildren().size() == 0) {  // check for empty tree
        treeView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    }
    t.consume();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the selectedItemProperty() is not updated, however the getSelectedIndices() is updated correctly. So you can add a listener to getSelectedIndices().

I use the following code to keep an observableList of selectedItems.(of type Folder)

```
  cnt_treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener((InvalidationListener) observable -> {
            ArrayList<Folder> tmmp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TreeItem<Folder> ti : cnt_treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()) {
                if (ti != null)
                    tmmp.add(ti.getValue());
                selectedFolders.setAll(tmmp);
            }

        });
```

Found this solution on
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2393837/change-listener-not-notified-when-tree-item-is-deselected

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, you should pass an observable collection to your root node.

In your code, instead of:

```
    final TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Item " + i));
    }
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
```

add following properties:

```
private ObservableList<TreeItem<String>> obsTreeItems;
private List<TreeItem<String>> treeItems;
```

and change your first lines with:

```
    treeItems = new ArrayList<>();
    final TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        /*root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("Item " + i));*/
        treeItems.add(new TreeItem<String>("Item "+i));
    }
    //observable collection
    obsTreeItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList(treeItems);

    //add items as observable list to root
    root.getChildren().addAll(obsTreeItems);

    treeView.setShowRoot(false);
    treeView.setRoot(root);
```

You'll notice that the update will be done well this time. You should remove aswel all the workaround code. The update button will not be needed anymore.

Comment: Using ObservableList as input to `addAll` wont change the behaviour of the root-children. The implementation of `addAll` goes through the given collection (!) with a foreach and executes an `add` on the target. So it makes no difference what kind of collection you put into `addAll` or if you call `add` on the target for each element.